# clock() and usleep() don't match up

Tags: c

I'm sending packets from a sender thread to a receiver thread. To control the send rate (packets per second), I calculate the time I need to wait before sending the next packet to maintain a certain send rate.

Let's say the time needed to wait was calculated to be 100 microseconds.

1. I check what time it is: `(double)(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`
2. I call `usleep(100);`
3. I check what time it is again: `(double)(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`

in step 3, when I check what time it is only 50 microseconds have passed (I checked the return value of `usleep` and confirmed it is returning 0).

Why is this? shouldn't it be sleeping for *at least* 100 microseconds? Or is there a different sleep function I should be using with `clock()`? Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What does `usleep` return? 0 or -1?

Comment: usleep is returning 0. how do I get the wall clock time?

Comment: nevermind i found an example. thanks Joachim!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock) function is defined to give you elapsed process time, not the wall clock (which unfortunately the Windows Visual Studio runtime library gives you). If your process isn't actually running, because it's sleeping, then no processor time will pass

How to get the walltime depends on your platform, but on POSIX (like Linux, OSX or the BSD variants) the recommended way is [`clock_gettime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) with the `CLOCK_REALTIME` clock.

Comment: The MSVC `clock` function is a non-standard implementation. Windows also has the [`GetProcessTimes` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms683223) and the [`QueryProcessCycleTime` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684929) but not `clock_gettime`.